# I want to search for the particular word and then after that word on each line i want to add ; in the start

Tags: vbscript

Using below code I was able to add `;` in the start of each line but the I want to add `;` after a particular word is found e.g. `[Abc]`. How to do this using VBScript?

```
Const ForReading=1
Const ForWriting=2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\sam.txt", ForReading)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    strText = f.ReadLine
    If Len(strText) = 0 Then
        blnFound = True
        MsgBox "blank line found"
        strText = vbNewLine & strText
        strContents = strContents & strText & vbCrlf
    Else
        strText = ";" & strText
        strContents = strContents & strText & vbCrlf
    End If
Loop

f.Close

Set f = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\sam.txt", Forwriting)
f.WriteLine strContents
f.Close
```

`Sam.txt` is containing some lines, e.g.

```
Hi, need help
This is a sample text file
[Abc]
How are you
Hope you are doing well!
```

So I want the output `sam.txt` file should have below data inside it:

```
Hi, need help
This is a sample text file
[Abc]
;How are you
;Hope you are doing well!
```

Comment: replace it; `strText = replace(strText, "[Abc]", "[Abc];")`

Comment: Thank you for replying on my post but i want the below output.

Sam.txt is containing some lines for e.g

Hi, need help
This is a sample text file 
[Abc]
How are you 
Hope you are doing well!

So I want the output sam.txt file should have below data inside it :-

Hi, need help
This is a sample text file
[Abc]
;How are you
;Hope you are doing well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically, you have an INI-style file and want the entries in a particular section commented. That can be achieved like this:

```
filename = "D:\sam.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt = Split(fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll, vbNewLine)

disable = False
For i = 0 To UBound(txt)
  If Left(txt(i), 1) = "[" Then
    If txt(i) = "[Abc]" Then
      disable = True
    Else
      disable = False
    End If
  End If

  If disable Then txt(i) = ";" & txt(i)
Next

fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2).Write Join(txt, vbNewLine)
```

Comment: yes you are right..but the thing is that there are multiple files and in one file multiple sections are present and i want to comment out particular section according to the requirement from that particular file.can you help me to figure out how to search a particular section and comment out that section.Thank you.

Comment: yes but every time the file name and the section name are different so, i want it to be accepted from user through cmd or input dialogue box.But i am not getting it how to use inputbox in script.                                               strAns1= InputBox(“Please enter a name for your new file:”)
Wscript.Echo strAns1

strAns2 = InputBox(“Please enter a the section name”)
Wscript.Echo strAns2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit 

Dim FSO ' Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim ReadTxtFile, WriteTxtFile ' Object
Dim TextLine, TextLineToWrite ' String
Dim AddStr' bool

' Open both text file in the same time
Set ReadTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("Sam.txt", 1) ' Open file to read
Set WriteTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("Sam_new.txt", 2, True) ' Open file to write

' Do read file as normal but add a switch
' Write original text line to text file while switch is disabled
' Add str to the text line  and write once switch is trigger 

AddStr = False ' Add str disabled
Do Until ReadTextFile.AtEndOfStream ' Start Read

    Textline = ReadTextFile.Readline 

    If AddStr = True Then ' If add str enabled
        TextLineToWrite = ";" & Textline ' Add string
    Else ' if add str disabled
        TextLineToWrite = Textline ' write original line
    End If

    If Trim(Textline) = "[ABC]" Then ' If indicator read
        AddStr = True ' add str write
    End if

    WriteTextFile.WriteLine TextLineToWrite ' Write file when each line is read
Loop

ReadTextFile.Close
WriteTextFile.Close

msgbox "Done"
```

Comment: Sorry, suppose to be `Set WriteTextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(...)` And also change  `Dim StartWrite` to `Dim AddStr`